# PIO CLI support for normal Android

Tags: kernel, aosp, peripherals

Question is simple, is it possible to integrate PIO CLI tool to normal AOSP project for cellular device?

According to my current knowledge Android Things OS is not open sourced, at least not entirely. But there is a little info on the internet. I've checked the aosp manifest branches and there are some present for Android IoT. But after taking a quick look into them it seems there is nothing regarding peripheral tool. Other than that I've no idea where to look for this.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/pio-cli

Comment: I asked about possibility of integration of this tool. How page describing functionality is suppose to help me?

Comment: i have just added this link for others so they must not search for what PIO CLI is (like i did)